# Add desktop support to an existing Flutter app

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop-application

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .
```

On executing the above command I am getting the following error.

'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/200/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) turorial. You probably do not have flutter inside your environment variables

Comment: The code is running in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: You are running the code in a terminal in Edge?

Comment: I am trying to apply the code for the desktop as well.